# pass the value of variable from a script to another script from another server

Tags: shell-script, ssh, scripting, variable

I have a script that will ssh to another server.

Script A will get the value of $variableA, then will ssh to another server to execute a script B which will need the value of $variableA.

I tried below but script B is not recognizing the value of $variableA

scriptA"

```
varA=`hostname`
ssh -x serverB "/home/dir/scriptb.sh $varA"
```

Script B from 2nd server:

```
echo $varA
```

ScriptB from 2nd server won't echo $varA.

Comment: perhaps scriptb needs `varA=$1` ?

Answer (score 0):

Your script `scriptb.sh` on remote server got that variable by value as the 1st positioned argument.
To output the 1st argument passed to shell script:

```
echo $1
```

Comment: also tried that. did not work

Comment: @oakley00 You should use `$1` in the script that executes remotely (instead of `$varA`). That ought to work. If not, update the text in the question with information about what "doesn't work".

Comment: Note that the content of `$varA` will be passed as the first argument to `scriptb.sh` only if it contains none of the special characters of the login shell of the user on the remote host. For instance, if `$varA` contained `$(reboot)` (quite unusual for a hostname) and the login shell of the user was POSIX-like, that would cause `reboot` to be called instead.